# attempted relative import with no known parent package (python)

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to import the db module from the `__init__` file, after comand `from . import db`, gets `attempted relative import with no known parent package`

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
app = Flask(__name__)
```

My catalog structure:

```
Procjet
├── __init__.py
├── auth.py
└── templates
```

i tried it:

`from . import db`

`from .. import db`

`from project import db`

`from .project import db`

and always i gets `attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: Pleas do not add unrelated tags. I was driven here because you tagged it `bash` whereas it is indeed a Python problem. I feel so much frustrated by the misleading tag, that I am not willing to help you at all.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the project folder directly in an IDE should fix the issue.

You could check if the correct path is in sys.path in debug mode for example.

Comment: Running in IDE gives the same error